# Can I use the verb "finish 'in present continuous tense?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses, present-continuous

Recently, in an essay, I used "finishing up" in a sentence. My teacher marked it wrong, because *to finish* something isn't an action that takes time. But I've heard "finishing up" used in real life. Is it grammatically correct to use *finish* in present continuous tense?

Comment: I don't see why not. It I was in the final stages of, say, making something and someone called to me, I might say "I'm just finishing - I'll be with you in a minute".

Comment: Your teacher is going against standard usage. I wonder what they think "half-finished" means? When someone says they're going to finish breakfast, for example, nobody takes that to be only about the future moment when the last mouthful is swallowed.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Have you looked up the word *finish* in a good dictionary for its meanings and usage examples?

Comment: _This is not the end. It is not even the beginning of the end. It is, perhaps, the end of the beginning._ - Churchill knows these things take time.

Comment: It depends on the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Any action, including finishing something, takes a measurable amount of time between its start and its completion. It's not possible for any action to occur instantaneously, even if its length of time isn't perceptible. There will always be some moment before and some moment after—and some amount of time in between those two moments.

Further, if you're able to *say* that you're finishing up, then what you're doing *is* taking a perceptible amount of time—at least as long as it takes to say that, but most likely longer.

Your teacher may have been confusing *finishing up* with something like this:

> *I am finished.*

That doesn't involve time, because [*finished*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finished) in that sentence is an adjective, not a verb, and it's describing a property or attribute.